# Jquery FullCalendar not working with URL on Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

In my fullcalendar event I've added the (Controller/action) "/Calendar/GetEvents/" for the event. This is not hitting the GetEvents method in CalendarController

I've included fullcalendar requirements in the _Layout

```
    <link href="~/Content/Template/assets/libs/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Content/Template/assets/libs/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Template/assets/libs/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Template/assets/libs/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

This is in my CalendarController method

```
    public JsonResult GetEvents(double start, double end)
    {

        var fromDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(start);
        var toDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(end);

        //Get the events
        var eventList = this.GetEvents();

        var rows = eventList.ToArray();
        return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In index view has id for calendar

```
    <div id="calendar"></div>
```

and the script

```
    @section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       theme: true,

       defaultView: 'agendaDay',
       editable: false,
       events: "/Calendar/GetEvents/"
       });
    });

    </script>

    }
```

as above script didn't work, I've tried following as the script also

```
    @section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header:
                {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title'
                },
                buttonText: {
                    today: 'today'
                },
                //defaultView: 'agendaDay',
                editable: false,
                //events: "/Calendar/GetEvents/"

                events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Calendar/GetCalendarData/',
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        //success: function (result) {
                        //    alert('yeap');
                        //},
                        //error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        //    alert('oops, something bad happened');
                        //}
                        success: function (result) {
                            var events = [];

                            $.each(result, function (i, data) {
                                events.push(
                                    {
                                        title: data.Title,
                                        //description: data.Desc,
                                        start: moment(data.Start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                                        end: moment(data.End).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                                        backgroundColor: "#9501fc",
                                        borderColor: "#fc0101"
                                    });
                            });
                            alert('hoo');
                            callback(events);
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            alert('failed');
                        }
                    });
                }

                //eventRender: function (event, element) {
                //    element.qtip(
                //    element.qtip(
                //        {
                //            content: event.description
                //        });
                //},

                //editable: false
            });
        });



</script>
}
```

Controller method for this script url

```
    public ActionResult GetCalendarData()
    {
        // Initialization.  
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();

        try
        {
            // Loading.  
            List<CalendarDay> data = this.LoadData();

            // Processing.  
            result = this.Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Info  
            Console.Write(ex);
        }

        // Return info.  
        return result;
    }
```

When I'm running it's showing calendar, but it's not hitting the action method in the controller and doesn't show the events in the calendar. When checking the browser can see the following

```
    MOCK GET: /Calendar/GetEvents/
    Object { url: "/Calendar/GetEvents/", type: "GET", isLocal: false, global: true, processData: true, async: true, contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", accepts: {…}, contents: {…}, responseFields: {…}, … }
```

Comment: I think the problem is that your action `GetEvents` expect two parameters `start` and `end` and you don't send any in your ajax call so the routing engine doesn't find it. I'm not sure how to do it in your first javascript example but it should be explained in fullcalendar documentation.

Comment: Sorry @colinD I've added the method for ajax call. It still same problem

Comment: @colinD Actually in the first example (`events: "/Calendar/GetEvents/"`) fullCalendar would add the start and end dates to the request automatically - since in this case fullCalendar is building the AJAX request itself. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed

Comment: @LionalSandun I think `GetEvents(double start, double end)` should be `GetEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end)` - if you look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed it shows you that the dates are appended to the request in `yyyy-mm-dd` format - which would be parseable into a `DateTime`, but not into a `double`

Comment: Also.. `MOCK GET:` in the console is odd...I haven't seen that before. I am only guessing, but are you maybe using some other JS library which is intended to make all your AJAX requests fake, for testing?

Comment: If not, maybe that's a red herring...but have you looked at the Network tab of the browser tools to see if a request to `/GetEvents` is actually fired? And if so, what response code and data comes back, if any? Open the network tool before loading your calendar, and then watch it while the request takes place.

Comment: Can you successfully make the request using Postman (or similar)?

Comment: @ADyson in network tab can't see the GetEvents get fired

Comment: Calling get method from local host returns json

        0 
        id 1
        start "/Date(1555589491316)/"
        end "/Date(1555762291316)/"
        title "EventName 1"